# Google Container Engine - How to auto-scale an instance group based on HTTP load?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, autoscaling, google-kubernetes-engine

In Google Container Engine, when using an L7 ingress, what’s the correct way to auto-scale an instance group based on HTTP load?

When I try to enable auto-scaling for my instance group, I get the warning that I must add the instance group the L7 ingress’ backend service. However, the backend service is already using a k8-ig group, which I cannot enable auto-scaling for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoscaling based on HTTP load is not currently supported through the Ingress. You can of course grow the size of you GKE cluster. *Pod autoscaling* has been discussed before in the context of https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18352 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/484. Please open an issue on the github repo if you'd like instance autoscaling.

Comment: I created an issue, thanks: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25334.